# Why does Scipy.misc.derivative give wrong answer Python

Tags: python, scipy

I try to plot the derivative of a piecewise function.

[image]

I worked out the math the derivative exists everything should be fine and I want to see what happen at the "singularity", but I get:

singularity at 'x=0'

[image]

which opposes to what I expect:

The "kind of" result I expect

[image]

My code:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative as deriv
import numpy as np
import pylab as pyl


def f(x):  # Define piecewise function
    if x != 0:
        h = np.power(x, -1)
        return x**2 * np.sin(h)
    elif x == 0:
        return 0


vf = np.vectorize(f)  # Vectorize function to use "deriv"

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=10 ** 5)  # Make 'x' continuous parameter
x = np.sort(np.append(x, [0]))  # Make sure 'x' contains '0'


def d(x): return deriv(vf, x)  # Define derivative of 'f' respect to 'x'


print('0, ' + str(d(0)))  # Derivative at '0'

pyl.plot(x, vf(x), 'b-')  # Plot functions
pyl.plot(x, d(x), 'C4')
pyl.scatter(0, d(0), c='r0')

pyl.grid()

pyl.show()  # Display graphically
```

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see.

Comment: I just updated my code! My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `f` sometimes returns an int, and if no explicit output dtype is specified, [`numpy.vectorize` guesses the output dtype by calling the underlying function on the first element of the input](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). That means that some of the `f` results in the derivative calculation are being coerced to integers, throwing off the results.

You can't just call `numpy.vectorize` on a function that doesn't handle arrays and assume everything will work out. You still have to pay attention to things like dtype and the other quirks in the docs, and it'll never be as fast as a function written to handle vectorized operation naturally.

---

The other problem is that, as explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html),

> scipy.misc.derivative(func, x0, dx=1.0, n=1, args=(), order=3)
>
> Find the n-th derivative of a function at a point.
>
> Given a function, use a central difference formula with spacing dx to compute the n-th derivative at x0.

`scipy.misc.derivative` uses a central difference formula, with a default spacing of 1. This step size is much larger than the size of the "wiggles" in your graph. You will have to specify a smaller step size to get useful derivative results.